# Mindjet Mind Mapping compatibility

Tags: 16.04, windows

I have Mindjet's Mind-Mapping tool.  On Ubuntu, I would like to have an [Ubuntu-Mind-Map program](http://www.junauza.com/2009/08/5-best-freeopen-source-mind-mapping.html) that has:

- The capability to open Mindjet Mind Maps
- Vice versa: open files Ubuntu Mind-maps in Mindjet

For this to happen, I would think that it would be neccesary to have a common file type.  Mindjet supports:

- .mmap
- .xmmap .xml
- .txt (outline)
- OPML (outline)

If you are successfully creating mindmaps on both OS and using them interchangeably between Windows / Ubuntu, please state this in your reply.

Questions:

1. Can Mindjet compatibility be achieved with any [Ubuntu Mind-Mapping
   Software](http://www.junauza.com/2009/08/5-best-freeopen-source-mind-mapping.html)?
2. If there is a more than one contender, which would you
   choose and why?

[A list of mind mapping instances is provided by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concept-_and_mind-mapping_software)

Comment: Did you try Xmind?

Comment: Its cross-platform and free for home users.

Comment: @Raphael, I have not tried anything yet because I wanted recommendations before trying anything.  Have you used Xmind and would you recommend it?  I have a feeling many are cross-platform and free, but I suspect that one is preferable

Comment: I have tried out many programs such as Freemind, etc. before settling on Xmind. It really is the best.

Comment: @Raphael: that is an excellent comment: exactly what I was seeking.  If you could comment on why Xmind is the superior to the others in my link, that would help others to make a good decision

Comment: @Raphael Have you had any success loading MindManager files with XMind?  I installed the snap but as soon as I click on the "Open File" button the program crashes.